# Programmatically close ant design rangepicker in react

Tags: reactjs, antd

I added a button in the extra footer in the range picker from antd. I wanted to close the range picker when I click the button. Does anyone know how to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control showing or hiding the picker by using `open` prop, like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <RangePicker
      open={open}
      onOpenChange={open => setOpen(open)}
      renderExtraFooter={() => <button onClick={()=> setOpen(false)}>Close</button>}
    />
  );
};
```

I've implemented an example also [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pp6pdm).

Comment: Thank you! I did not think "onOpenChange" would be useful, and I spent hours using open, onBlur, onFocus, and onCalendarChange.

Comment: on close, this is not setting value.